# I overstayed my Thai visa! What's going to happen to me?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, thailand, overstaying

I got my visa on arrival when I landed at Suvarnabhumi Airport back in February.

Somehow, I thought that my visa was valid until 23 March, so I booked my flight out of the country for the 23rd.

But when I arrived at the airport, I checked my passport, and it turns out my visa expired on **22** March!

What's going to happen when I get to passport control?  Will this prevent me from entering Thailand and/or acquiring visas in the future?

I'm a US citizen, if that is important.

Comment: A quick Google search turned up this, looks like you might be okay: http://www.thaivisa.com/visa-overstay-thailand.html

Comment: Wait, you are at the airport and you are asking this question here?!

Comment: out of interest, what was the outcome?

Comment: Everything went as normal until it came time for the officer to stamp my passport.  He called over another officer and gave her my passport.  She led me over to the area labeled (in very big letters) "FINE FOR OVERSTAY".  But, as I was only over by one day, she just stamped my passport as normal.  I didn't have to pay anything, and I didn't get the dreaded "OVERSTAY" stamp in my passport neither (:

Comment: That's lucky! A friend of mine overstayed 1 day in Thailand and had to pay a (small) fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thailand enforces a 500 Baht/day fine for overstaying a visa.  Although this is technically due for each day that you overstay including the first, it is often waived for overstaying only a single day. If you were to overstay by 2 days you can guarantee that you'd be hit with a 1000 baht fine, and so on up to a maximum fine of 20,000 baht.

They also stamp your passport with an "overstay" stamp to record the fact that you overstayed.  Whilst this will not block you from entering the country in the future, if you are found to overstay a second time you can expect additional action to be taken.  Again it's likely that they will not stamp your passport for a 1 day overstay.

Even though this fine seems relatively low (for a few days at least), it is NEVER a good idea to overstay a visa.  The fine applies if you are "caught" at the airport when departing the country.  If you are caught elsewhere in Thailand you can expect to be jailed for at least a day or two, and then deported from the country.  Again this is not likely to be an issue for a single day overstay, but for a longer overstay it could be!

Comment: There's another answer contradicting yours at present. It's very brief, which makes yours appear much more credible (plus the fact that their "no fine" could easily be a misunderstanding of the sitation you described where there is a fine but it's waived for a single day). However, if you could find a citation to back your answer up it would be nice to edit that in to avoid any possible confusion when people are reading different answers.

Comment: We exited Thailand at a land border point (to Malaysia) and accidentally overstayed by one day (we thought the train would cross the border before midnight). We were charged 500 baht each. I protested a little based on what I had read online, and the officer told me there is officially a 500 baht fine per day, but at some border points (not this one!) they will waive it for overstays of only one day. I imagine the waiver would be more likely at the main tourist entry/exit points like Suvarnabhumi Airport.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have reached the airport, just walk up to the immigration counter and explain to the officer why you overstayed. There's no fine for overstaying by a day.

Comment: The other answer seems to indicate that there *is* a fine, but it would usually get waived for a single day. Do you have a citation you can cite to clear this up?

Comment: Same thing happened to me once. The immigration said I overstayed one day, but he just gave me back my passport and off I went.

Answer (score 2):

I just got fined even just for one day also had the stamp overstay on passport. I left Thailand at Ranong border going into Myanmar and accidentally I had overstayed one day in Thailand. I didn't complain or argue, I apologized and had told them I was a bit sick and stayed on the island Koh Phayam. I had to pay 500 regardless.